# Localhost Invalid Certificate for Chrome 88

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, localhost, insecure-connection

I have a spring boot app on localhost, when I try to access it on Chrome 88, it shows the following error:

`You cannot visit localhost right now because the website sent scrambled credentials that Google Chrome cannot process. Network errors and attacks are usually temporary, so this page will probably work later.`

I found this post: [SSL Localhost Privacy error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35565278/ssl-localhost-privacy-error), but seems like in Chrome 88 the `Allow insecure localhost` option is no longer available. I was able to use the other answer on that post, which is to type `thisisunsafe` and hit `Enter`.

Is there another way to workaround this to not have to type `thisisunsafe` for every localhost sites?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a temporary fix you can turn on chrome://flags/#temporary-unexpire-flags-m87 which then allows you to turn on chrome://flags/#allow-insecure-localhost again.